# Execute Heroku Cedar Stack into Docker Container

Tags: java, git, heroku, docker

I would like to setup a Docker container using the following image: https://github.com/heroku/stack-images

I have installed the image inside Docker using

```
docker pull heroku/cedar:14
```

Which steps are required to start a Docker container that works in the same way Heroku does?

- Communicate via Heroku ToolBelt cli in order to start and scale the application
- Deploy applications using git and build using Java BuildPack

I've found an approach where you can turn an Heroku application into a Docker container but it is not the solution i'm looking for:

http://www.centurylinklabs.com/heroku-on-docker/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) project. It utilizes a docker project called [buildstep](https://github.com/progrium/buildstep) to run Heroku buildpacks in a Cedar-like environment.

Have fun!